# JavaScript API for Office Web Apps

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, ms-office

Is there a JavaScript API for Office Web Apps (specifically - Word Web App) that I can use in order to get notifications from the Word doc?

My scenario is this:

I have an ASP.NET application, in which I want to display a word document using the Word Web App (on premises). I would like to embed the document in the web page using iFrame (haven't tried it yet, hope it'll work...).

I would like to get notification when the user saved the document, so that when this happens, I can remove the iFrame and display something else.

Is that possible?

Comment: Where do you host the web apps? in a private farm or online (like office 365)?

Comment: In order to detect that a document has been saved you should create an EventHandler and on the ItemUpdated event invoke a statuschange in a webservice or similar that your top-page can read. This stuff is highly complicated.

Comment: Trikks - just to make sure, you're talking about a Sharepoint Service?

Comment: Is your asp.net application built in SharePoint? In that case yes otherwise no.

Comment: @Trikks What do you mean by "your top-page"? At least for me, OWA is displaying in its own page (and not inheriting from any master).

Comment: A top page would be the page that hosts the iframe today.

Answer (score 0):

I recently read MSDN article on this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891051.aspx. Hope that helps.

Comment: I believe that's for the desktop Office applications, not the Office Web Apps.